# Correct way of handling the output layer deltas in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, algorithms

According to Andrew Ng's Coursera Machine Learning course (notes [here](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/09_Neural_Networks_Learning.html) and [here](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/coursera-machine-learning-neural-networks/)), a training algorithm for neural nets is this:

1. $\delta^{(L)} = a^{(L)} - y$
2. $\text{for }l = L-1, ..., 2\text{ do}$
3. $\quad \delta^{(l)} = (\Theta^{(l)})^T \delta^{(l + 1)} .* g'(z^{(l)})$
4. $\text{end}$

Then, for computing the actual gradients:

1. $\text{Set }\Delta^{(l)} = 0,\text{ for }l = 1, ..., L-1$
2. $\text{for }i = 1, ..., m\text{ do}$
3. $\quad \text{Set }a^{(1)} = x^{(i)}$
4. $\quad \text{Compute }a^{(l)}\text{ for }l=2,...,L  \text{ using forward propagation (Algorithm 1)}$
5. $\quad \text{Using }y^{(i)}, \text{compute } \delta^{(l)} \text{ for } l = L, ..., 2  \\ \qquad\text{ using the backpropagation algorithm (Algorithm 2)}$
6. $\quad \Delta^{(l)} = \Delta^{(l)} + \delta^{(l+1)}(a^{(l)})^T \text{ for }l=L-1, ..., 1$
7. $\text{end}$

However, this seems to contradict [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-10s/Lecture/lecture7.pdf) (page 7, taken from Mitchell's book I believe, but also in various other tutorials: [here](https://takinginitiative.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/basic-neural-network-tutorial-theory/) and [here](http://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/comment-page-1/#comment-17063) for example), where the output layer delta is defined as:

$${\delta^{(L)} = (a^{(L)} - y}).*(a^{(L)}.*(1-a^{(L)}))$$

So the derivative of the output layer outputs is also factored in. In the above, $a$ always represents the output of a layer and $z$ is the "raw computation" of a layer, before the sigmoid function is applied to it. $.*$ is element-wise multiplication.

According to what I learned and understand, you should factor in the derivative as well. According to my experiments, things work a little better if you do, but I haven't been able to test too much.

Which is the correct way? Or are they equivalent but I misunderstood something about the first notation (and therefore also implemented it wrong)? Or it doesn't matter and I'll just need proper hyperparameters for each to obtain similar results?

[Here](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) is some code that shows what I mean:

```
X = np.array([ [0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1] ])
y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1
for j in xrange(60000):
    l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
    l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(l1,syn1))))
    l2_delta = (y - l2)*(l2*(1-l2)) #######################
    l1_delta = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T) * (l1 * (1-l1))
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += X.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

According to my understanding, Andrew Ng's version suggests replacing the line marked with hashtags with just this:

```
l2_delta = y - l2
```

Also according to my understanding, doing that would be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out my mistake.

**Both versions are correct under the right loss function**.

Andrew Ng's version uses log loss:

$$
J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Big(y_ilog\big(h_\theta(x_i)\big)+(1-y_i)log\big(1-h_\theta(x_i)\big)\Big)
$$

Where:

$$
h_\theta(x) = g(x\theta) = \frac{1}{1+exp(-x\theta)}
$$

Let's take the derivative of this (I'm shortening this a little by dropping the sum) with respect to $\theta$:

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Big(ylog\big(h_\theta(x)\big)+(1-y)log\big(1-h_\theta(x)\big)\Big) \\
&=y\frac{1}{h_\theta(x)}g(x\theta)\big(1-g(x\theta)\big)x+(1-y)\frac{1}{1-h_\theta(x)}g(x\theta)\big(g(x\theta)-1\big)x \\
&=y\big(1-g(x\theta)\big)x-(1-y)g(x\theta)x \\
&=yx-yg(x\theta)x-g(x\theta)x+yg(x\theta)x \\
&=\big(y-g(x\theta)\big)x
\end{align}
$$

Mitchell's version uses squared loss, which is defined along these lines:

$$
J(\theta)=-\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Big(y_i-h_\theta(x_i)\Big)^2
$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$ as we did above, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Big(y-h_\theta(x)\Big)^2\\
&=2\big(y-h_\theta(x)\big)g(x\theta)\big(g(x\theta)-1\big)x \\
&=2\big(h_\theta(x)-y\big)g(x\theta)\big(1-g(x\theta)\big)x
\end{align}
$$

I missed the fact that they were using different loss functions. Both versions are correct.